Why is interpolating $y=g(x)$ then applying $h(y)$ not equivalent to interpolating $h(g(x))$?
Say I have a table of voltage, current, and resistance values as so.



V [V]
I [A]
R [$\Omega$]




1
2
0.5


3
5
0.6



The V and I columns are measurements, R is a simple calculation from Ohm's law (V=IR).
Now say I want to linearly interpolate the resistance value at I=3.5A.
I can do this two ways. The first way is to interpolate the value of V first, then reapply Ohm's law:
We'd have:
$$1 + (3.5 - 2) \frac{  3 - 1 }{5 - 2} = 2\text{ V}$$
Reapplying Ohm's law: 2V/3.5A = 0.571$\Omega$.
The second way would be to interpolate R directly:
$$0.5 + (3.5 - 2) \frac{0.6 - 0.5}{5 - 2} = 0.55\Omega$$
Now, my question is, why aren't these equivalent?
I've plugged the two expressions (1) (2) into Wolfram Alpha and I can see they are not equivalent, but I am having a hard time proving why.
Thanks

@Semiclassical You are right. I've corrected the typo.

First, an objection: I don't think the title formulation matches the context provided. In the first case, you approximate $V(I)\approx V_L(I)$ via linear interpolation and then compute $V_L(I)/I$. In the second case, you instead use values of $R(I)=V(I)/I$ and linearly interpolate to get $R_L(I)$. But $R(I)=V(I)/I$ can't be straightforwardly expressed as $h(V(I))$, so framing this in terms of function composition seems like the wrong focus.
There is however a straightforward reason for the failure in the present case. When we linearly interpolate to get $V_L(I)$ and $R_L(I)$, the results are by construction linear functions of $I$. But if we compute $V_L(I)/I$, then the result is manifestly non-linear in $I$. Hence there's no way the two routes could ever give equivalent results within the interpolation interval. (They do, of course, agree on the endpoints.)

I don't the OP was thinking of it this way, but if the function $V()$ is invertible, then we can fit this into the function composition framing by using $h(y) = y/V^{-1}(y)$ (please forgive the the choice of variables - it's hard to be thorough in a comment).

Good point---I'd overlooked that. It's a bit of a strange case since it explicitly involves $V^{-1}(y)$, but I'll adjust my phrasing accordingly.

Yeah, it's a pretty sketchy maneuver, and it probably doesn't make things clearer for the OP - I just added it for completeness. I know comments are supposed to be used to update an answer, but it's probably best left as a comment, and if it goes away, no great loss.

Well, the most I did was qualify my claim to it not being straightforwardly expressed. So I think those weasel words will suffice.

I agree. ${}{}{}$

@Semiclassical Thanks. I've plotted this quickly and can see $V_L(I)/I$ is not linear.

@jrecord To see it without plotting: a linear function is of the form $V_L(I)=aI+b$, so $V_L(I)/I=a+b/I$ is no longer linear in $I$. (It is, however, linear in $1/I$. There might be a way to exploit that but I can't be bothered to work it out.)

Interpolation treats your function as if it's a line (i.e. linear function) between your two interpolation endpoints. If your function $h( )$ preserved "being a line" then you would get the same value both ways, but it doesn't.
Another way to think about this is that interpolating $h\circ g$ maps the endpoints, and then connects them with a line, but the other way maps the endpoints with $g$, draws the line between those, and then applies $h$ to that line, Unless $h$ is very simple, applying $h$ bends that line, so points in the middle get sent to a different value than the line that the first method drew.
Note: This answers the question posed in the title. If, as noted in the answer by @Semiclassical, that's not the actual computation being done, then this isn't quite right, but I'll leave it up as I suspect it's basically the same phenomenon taking place, and that it still provides insight on what is happening.

I've removed my referenced comment for the moment, but will be putting up an answer with it in a bit.

@Semiclassical - Okay, sounds good. I don't think I'm going to dig into the actual computation any more deeply, so please feel free to salvage anything useful from my answer and incorporate into yours, should you find anything.

I've added mine.
